# Querying a list that has 16967 items returns null reference exceptions when no results

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-pcl

I have a list with 16967 items and when querying the list and no results are found instead of count = 0 or zero results it throws, "**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**" is throwing.

```
var result = englishWords.Where(c => c.engWord.StartsWith(searchWord.ToLower()));
```

when the result of the querying is no results, the variable "result" is throwing null reference exception instead of zero results or no result. Any help would be appreciated?

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> 12-28 13:32:08.284 E/mono-rt ( 8929):   at TigrinyaDictionary.Views.ItemsPage+<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<MainSearchBar_TextChanged>b__0 (TigrinyaDictionary.Models.EngWord c) [0x00000] in C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Projects\Dictionary\MobileApp\TigrinyaDictionary\TigrinyaDictionary\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.cs:202
> 12-28 13:32:08.284 E/mono-rt ( 8929):   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs:574  12-28 13:32:08.284 E/mono-rt ( 8929):   at System.Linq.Enumerable+EnumerablePartition`1[TSource].ToList () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Partition.cs:629
> 12-28 13:32:08.284 E/mono-rt ( 8929):   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs:30
> 12-28 13:32:08.284 E/mono-rt ( 8929):   at TigrinyaDictionary.Views.ItemsPage.MainSearchBar_TextChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e) [0x00220] in C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Projects\Dictionary\MobileApp\TigrinyaDictionary\TigrinyaDictionary\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.cs:205

[image]

Comment: One of the entries in `englishWords` is `null` or has a `engWord` property that is `null`.

Comment: Don't use null like mjwills suggests.  A When you not return a null.  Instead use result.Count() > 0;

Comment: The `IEnumerable<T>` returned by `Where` has no `Count` property. It has a `Count()` *method*. What you posted shouldn't even compile. The screenshot doesn't show any NullReferenceException, it shows that if you try to retrieve an IEnumerator instance from the query result while the debugger has stopped the application, you'd get an exception. `result` is *always* non-null

Comment: Sorry I have two variables: result and results:
Here is how the code looks like
 var result = englishWords?.Where(c => c.engWord.StartsWith(searchWord.ToLower()));
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        results = result.Select(c => c.engWord).Take(5).ToList();
                    }

Comment: Get rid of the `null` check - it does nothing useful.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in the watch window you can see the "result" variable is throwing a null reference exception

Comment: Now that we have the stack trace, it looks like the actual exception occured *inside* the `Where` call, most likely because one of the `engWord` values was a `NULL` to begin with. Either check for `null` in `Where` or use the null-safe operator, `?.`, eg `.Where(c => c.engWord?.StartsWith(searchWord.ToLower())`. Or perhaps `searchWord` is null?

Comment: @kiflay that image is irrelevant and the error doesn't even occur in there. The exception's stack trace occurs in a different place, inside the `Where` call

Comment: Does changing to `var result = englishWords.Where(c => c?.engWord?.StartsWith(searchWord?.ToLower() ?? string.Empty) ?? false);` work?

Comment: BTW you don't need `ToLower()` either. You can use [String.StartsWith(string,StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_System_StringComparison_) to perform a case-insensitive search